# how can i make css for <p title="titlehere"></p>

Tags: html, css

I have this code, which displays the button shown below:

```
<p class="head_ico_p" title="profile"><img class="head_ico" src="images/profile.png"/></p>
```

[image]

I would like to style the title (tooltip) using CSS so that it looks like that in the image below:

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML

```
<p class="head_ico_p" title="profile">
   <img class="head_ico" src="https://app.getfloop.com/img/dashboard/app/placeholder-app-icon.png"/>
</p>
<p class="caption">Edit Profile</p>
```

CSS

```
    .head_ico_p{
        width:100px;
        margin:20px auto 0;
        text-align:center;
    }
    img{
        width:70px;
    }
    .caption{
        display:block;
        width:100px;
        margin:0 auto;
        background:#333;
        color:#fff;
        text-align:center;
        padding:10px
    }
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/mVzGVw)

Answer (score 0):

### Snippet:

You can achieve the desired effect as shown below:

```css
.head_ico_p[title]:hover:after {
  content:attr(title);
  background-color:#000000;
  border:solid 1px #ffffff;
  padding:5px;
  color:#ffffff;
  display:block;
  width:330px;
  height:30px;
}
body {
  background-color:#dddddd;
}
```

```html
<p class="head_ico_p" title="profile"><img class="head_ico" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150"/></p>
```

### How it works:

- The `:after` psudeo-class is used in CSS to add another "element" **after** the element that is being selected. This element can be effected by all standard styles and selectors, such as `:hover`. Note that a `:before` psudeo-class also exists, for adding another "element" **before** the element being selected.
- The `content` attribute can set the content of an element created by `:before` or `after` to a predefined value. This can be specified in the CSS (`content:"xyz";`) or by an attribute. The latter is what you are looking for, and uses the CSS `attr` function to pull the contents of an attribute into the CSS code as the value for `content`.

The code shown in the JSFiddle above uses a combination of the above (and some other basic CSS) to create the desired tooltip effect.

### Improvments:

- Other answers think that you're wanting it there constantly, this assumes that you want it as a tooltip (like `title`). If you don't want it to disappear when you're not hovering, all that you need to do is remove the `:hover` psudeo-class from the CSS selector making the tooltip.
- Maybe consider data attributes rather than `title`, as `title` can render a default tooltip on hover (the browser does this). Code with data attributes would simply use `data-xyz` instead of all occurrences of `title`. Note that `xyz` can be replaced by whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.test{
 display:inline-block;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 width:80px;
 height:110px;
 background:url('http://s15.postimg.org/fjgl2u3h3/Cvt_Lr.png') no-repeat #000;
 color:#fff;
 background-color:#000;
 text-align:center;
 padding-top:85px;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<a class="test" href="#">Profile</a>
</body>
</html>

somethin like that. But you will need to cut the white space from the image. Hope it helps
```